# Dataframe iteration using Numba instead of itertuples() for faster code

Tags: pandas, numpy, performance, vectorization, numba

**My problem**

I have three dataframes which I am using itertuples to loop through.

Itertuples worked well for a time however now I am running too many iterations for itertuples to be efficient enough.

I'd like to use vectorisation or perhaps Numba as I have heard that they are both very fast. I've tried to make them work but I can't figure it out

All three dataframes are Open, High, Low, Close candlestick data with a few other columns i.e 'FG_Top'

The dataframes are

1. `dflong` - 15 minute candlestick data
2. `dfshort` - 5 minute candlestick data
3. `dfshorter` - 1 minute candlestick data

Dataframe creation code as requested in comments

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

idx15m = ['2022-10-29 06:59:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:14:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:29:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:44:59.999',
         '2022-10-29 07:59:59.999', '2022-10-29 08:14:59.999', '2022-10-29 08:29:59.999']

opn15m = [19010, 19204, 19283, 19839, 19892, 20000, 20192]
hgh15m = [19230, 19520, 19921, 19909, 20001, 20203, 21065]
low15m = [18782, 19090, 19245, 19809, 19256, 19998, 20016]
cls15m = [19204, 19283, 19839, 19892, 20000, 20192, 20157]

FG_Bottom = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 19909, np.nan]
FG_Top = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 19998, np.nan]

dflong = pd.DataFrame({'Open': opn15m, 'High': hgh15m, 'Low': low15m, 'Close': cls15m, 'FG_Bottom': FG_Bottom, 'FG_Top': FG_Top},
                  index=idx15m)

idx5m = ['2022-10-29 06:59:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:05:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:10:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:15:59.999',
         '2022-10-29 07:20:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:25:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:30:59.999']

opn5m = [19012, 19102, 19165, 19747, 19781, 20009, 20082]
hgh5m = [19132, 19423, 19817, 19875, 20014, 20433, 21068]
low5m = [18683, 19093, 19157, 19758, 19362, 19893, 20018]
cls5m = [19102, 19165, 19747, 19781, 20009, 20082, 20154]

price_end5m = [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]

dfshort = pd.DataFrame({'Open': opn5m, 'High': hgh5m, 'Low': low5m, 'Close': cls5m, 'price_end': price_end5m},
                  index=idx5m)

idx1m = ['2022-10-29 06:59:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:01:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:02:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:03:59.999',
         '2022-10-29 07:04:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:05:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:06:59.999']

opn1m = [19010, 19104, 19163, 19748, 19783, 20000, 20087]
hgh1m = [19130, 19420, 19811, 19878, 20011, 20434, 21065]
low1m = [18682, 19090, 19154, 19754, 19365, 19899, 20016]
cls1m = [19104, 19163, 19748, 19783, 20000, 20087, 20157]

price_end1m = [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]

dfshorter = pd.DataFrame({'Open': opn1m, 'High': hgh1m, 'Low': low1m, 'Close': cls1m, 'price_end': price_end1m},
                  index=idx1m)
```

Give 3 DataFrames that a similar to this following DataFrame

**Example Dataframe**

```
                             Open      High  ...          FG_Top          FG_Bottom
2022-10-29 06:59:59.999  20687.83  20700.46  ...             NaN                NaN
2022-10-29 07:14:59.999  20686.82  20695.74  ...             NaN                NaN
2022-10-29 07:29:59.999  20733.62  20745.30  ...        20733.62           20700.46
2022-10-29 07:44:59.999  20741.42  20762.75  ...             NaN                NaN
2022-10-29 07:59:59.999  20723.86  20777.00  ...             NaN                NaN
...                           ...       ...  ...             ...                ...
2022-11-10 02:14:59.999  16140.29  16167.09  ...             NaN                NaN
2022-11-10 02:29:59.999  16119.99  16195.19  ...             NaN                NaN
2022-11-10 02:44:59.999  16136.63  16263.15  ...             NaN                NaN
2022-11-10 02:59:59.999  16238.91  16238.91  ...             NaN                NaN
2022-11-10 03:14:59.999  16210.23  16499.00  ...             NaN                NaN
```

**Code explaination:**

I have my first dataframe which I loop over with the first loop, then loop again with a second nested loop. I have if statements checking certain conditions on each iteration and if those conditions are met then I make some values on the first dataframe np.nan

One of the conditions checked in the second loop calls a function which contains a third loop and checks for certain conditions in the other 2 dataframes.

```
# First loop

        for fg_candle_idx, row in enumerate(dflong.itertuples()):
            top = row.FG_Top
            bottom = row.FG_Bottom
            fg_candle_time = row.Index
            if (pd.notnull(top)):

# Second loop

                for future_candle_idx, r in enumerate(dflong.itertuples()):
                    future_candle_time = r.Index
                    next_future_candle = future_candle_time + timedelta(minutes=minutes)
                    future_candle_high = r.High
                    future_candle_low = r.Low
                    future_candle_close = r.Close
                    future_candle_open = r.Open
                    if future_candle_idx > fg_candle_idx:
                        div = r.price_end

# Check conditions, call function check_no_divs

                        if (pd.isnull(check_no_divs(dfshort, future_candle_time, next_future_candle))) & (
                        pd.isnull(check_no_divs(dfshorter, future_candle_time, next_future_candle))) & (
                        pd.isnull(div)):

                            if future_candle_high < bottom:
                                continue

                            elif future_candle_low > top:
                                continue

                            elif (future_candle_close < bottom) & \
                                    (future_candle_open > top):
                                dflong.loc[fg_candle_time, 'FG_Bottom'] = np.nan
                                dflong.loc[fg_candle_time, 'FG_Top'] = np.nan
                                continue

# Many additional conditions checked...
```

The following code is the function check_no_divs

```
    def check_no_divs(df, candle_time, next_candle):

        no_divs = []

# Third Loop

        for idx, row in enumerate(df.itertuples()):
            compare_candle_time = row.Index
            div = row.price_end
            if (compare_candle_time >= candle_time) & (compare_candle_time <= next_candle):
                if pd.notnull(div):
                    no_divs.append(True)
                else:
                    no_divs.append(False)

            elif compare_candle_time < candle_time:
                continue

            elif compare_candle_time > next_candle:
                break

        if all(no_divs) == False:
            return np.nan

        elif any(no_divs) == True:
            return 1
```

**Ideal Solution**

Clearly using itertuples is far too inefficient for this problem. I think that there would be a much faster solution to this issue using efficient vectorisation or Numba.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

p.s. I'm still quite new to coding, i think my current code could be made more efficient still using itertuples but probably not efficient enough. I'd appreciate it if someone knows a way to greatly increase the speed of this code

Comment: Tip: instead of a printed out dataframe, try adding it in a way so that the code can be copied and run. Like: `dflong = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, ...]], columns=['Open',...])`. That way someone can copy it to their own machine and easily run quick tests to see how it can be made faster.

Comment: @Mercury Thanks for the tip, makes sense. It's a bit hard with this dataframe as it's API data with a lot of additional calculations done on it over hundreds of lines of code to create the final dataframe that I'm working with. Not really something I can add without all the additional code. But I will try to do what you suggest with a dataframe that is similar

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time researching and testing different code and came up with this solution using numba which gives a significant speed boost.

first import the required libraries

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numba import njit, prange
```

Then define the function using numbas njit decotator

```
    @njit
    def filled_fg(fg_top, fg_bottom, dflongindex, Open, High, Low, Close, dflongprice_end,
                              dfshortprice_end, shortindex, dfshorterprice_end, shorterindex, conflu_top,
                              conflu_bottom):
# First loop
        for i in prange(len(fg_top)):
            top = fg_top[i]
            bottom = fg_bottom[i]
            if top is not np.nan:
                if (bottom - top) > 0:
                    fg_top[i] = np.nan
                    fg_bottom[i] = np.nan
# Second loop
                    for j in prange(len(fg_top)):
                        if j > i:
                            future_candle_time = dflongindex[j]
                            next_future_candle = dflongindex[j + 1]
                            future_candle_high = High[j]
                            future_candle_low = Low[j]
                            future_candle_close = Close[j]
                            future_candle_open = Open[j]
                            long_div = dflongprice_end[j]
# Check conditions
                            if ((new_check_no_divs(dfshortprice_end, shortindex, future_candle_time,
                                                   next_future_candle)) == np.nan) & ((new_check_no_divs(
                                dfshorterprice_end, shorterindex, future_candle_time,
                                next_future_candle)) == np.nan) & (long_div == np.nan):

                                if future_candle_high < bottom:
                                    continue


                                elif future_candle_low > top:
                                    continue

# Do something when conditions are met...
                                elif (future_candle_close < bottom) & \
                                        (future_candle_open > top):
                                    fg_bottom[i] = np.nan
                                    fg_top[i] = np.nan
                                    continue
```

Define the second function also with numbas njit decorator

```
    @njit
    def check_no_divs(div_data, div_candle_time, first_future_candle, second_future_candle):

        no_divs = []

        for i in prange(len(div_data)):
            if (div_candle_time[i] >= first_future_candle) & (div_candle_time[i] <= second_future_candle):
                if div_data[i] is not np.nan:
                    return 1
                else:
                    no_divs.append(0)
            elif div_candle_time[i] < first_future_candle:
                continue

            elif div_candle_time[i] > second_future_candle:
                break

        div_count = 0
        for i in no_divs:
            div_count = div_count + i
        if div_count == 0:
            return np.nan
```

Before calling the function dataframe indexes need to be reset

```
    dflong = dflong.reset_index()
    dfshort = dfshort.reset_index()
    dfshorter = dfshorter.reset_index()
```

Now call the function and use .values to return a numpy representation of the DataFrame.

```
fg_bottom, fg_top = filled_fg(dflong['FG_Top'].values,
                                                 dflong['FG_Bottom'].values,                                           
                                                 dflong['index'].values,
                                                 dflong['Open'].values,
                                                 dflong['High'].values,
                                                 dflong['Low'].values,
                                                 dflong['Close'].values,
                                                 dflong['price_end'].values,
                                                 dfshort['price_end'].values,
                                                 dfshort['index'].values,
                                                 dfshorter['price_end'].values,
                                                 dfshorter['index'].values)
```

Finally the returned data needs to be readded to the original DataFrame dflong

```
    dflong['FG_Bottom'] = fg_bottom
    dflong['FG_Top'] = fg_top
```

Speed test results:

Original itertuples solution = 7.641393423080444 seconds

New Numba solution = 0.5985264778137207 seconds