# Numba: No implementation of function Function(<built-in function setitem>) found for signature:

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I was able to use Numba to solve a slow itertuples iteration issue with code provided in the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74527898/dataframe-iteration-using-numba-instead-of-itertuples-for-faster-code?noredirect=1#comment131564958_74527898) however when I try it on a new function with a similar loop format i run into this error

```
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function setitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> setitem(array(float64, 1d, C), int64, datetime64[ns])
 
There are 16 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 16 did not match due to:
      Overload of function 'setitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
        With argument(s): '(array(float64, 1d, C), int64, datetime64[ns])':
       No match.

During: typing of setitem at C:\....

File "dtb.py", line 774:
    def RI_finder(idx, start_dtm, end_dtm):
        <source elided>
                                if #check conditions:
                                    start_dtm[i] = start_idx
                                    ^
```

There are some existing questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160311/does-numba-support-in-built-python-function-e-g-setitem/67165083#67165083), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68079673/is-there-a-numba-workaround-for-built-in-function-setitem-or-a-way-for-numba-t), that have a similar issue however the solutions provided don't fix my error.

Here is a sample of my code

```
    @njit
    def RI_finder(idx, start_dtm, end_dtm):

        for i in prange(len(start_dtm)):
            end_idx = idx[i]

            if #check conditions:
                for j in prange(len(start_dtm)):
                    start_idx = idx[j]

                    if #check conditions:

                        for k in prange(len(start_dtm)):
                            if #check conditions

                        if #check conditions
                            start_dtm[i] = start_idx
                            end_dtm[i] = end_idx
```

and here is a sample dataframe from which I am extracting the data used in the code provided

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start_dtm = ['2022-10-29 06:59:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:14:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:29:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:44:59.999',
         '2022-10-29 07:59:59.999', '2022-10-29 08:14:59.999', '2022-10-29 08:29:59.999']

end_dtm = ['2022-10-29 06:59:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:05:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:10:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:15:59.999',
         '2022-10-29 07:20:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:25:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:30:59.999']

idx = ['2022-10-29 06:59:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:01:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:02:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:03:59.999',
         '2022-10-29 07:04:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:05:59.999', '2022-10-29 07:06:59.999']

df = pd.DataFrame({'start_dtm': start_dtm, 'end_dtm': end_dtm}, index=idx)
```

What I am attempting is to loop through the arrays and find when certain conditions are met.

Once those conditions are met I update start_dtm, end_dtm.

Seeing as my code is so similar in structure to the code in [this questions answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74527898/dataframe-iteration-using-numba-instead-of-itertuples-for-faster-code?noredirect=1#comment131564958_74527898), (multiple loops to check conditions and then make changes). I can't see why mine is not working the same

Edit:
As suggested, making sure the variables are the same type worked to stop the error I was getting however now I am getting a new error which I have been unable to solve also.

```
non-precise type array(pyobject, 1d, C)

During: typing of argument at C: ....

File "dtb.py", line 734:
    def RI_finder(idx, start_dtm, end_dtm):
        <source elided>

        for i in prange(len(open)):
        ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you simplified the question and added a reproducible example.

But based on the Exception, it looks like you're trying to set the item with a different incompatible type:
`setitem(array(float64, 1d, C), int64, datetime64[ns])`

```py
start_dtm   = float64
i           = int64
start_idx   = datetime64[ns]
```

Making sure both `start_dtm` and `start_idx` share the same datatype would probably solve the issue.

edit:

The error related to the "pyobject 1D" seems to be cause by the `len()` function not supporting object type arrays, which is caused by Pandas in this case. It can be reproduced by something like:

```py
@njit
def func(x):
    return len(x)

func(np.asarray(["x"], dtype=object))
```

I'm not sure what the idea behind it all is, but casting all three arrays to datetime (`pd.to_datetime(start_dtm)`) solves that, or making it a string type should also work.

Comment: I simplified the question as much as I could as you requested and also added a reproducible example.  Your solution appears to have fixed the error I was getting and now there is a new error.

Comment: Thanks, the `if #check conditions:` parts aren't valid Python. But the exeption seems to be related to the datatype (=object) of the input arrays.